# DialogFlow Agent does not return result of nested axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, dialogflow-es

I am trying to integrate an external API with my dialogflow agent.
I have the pay as you use plan. I am trying to do nested API calls(sequentially) and then creating a dynamic sentence which I want my agent to speak.

The problem is that I can see the `console.log()` in the Logs Explorer but the agent does NOT speak the sentence out.

I am using separate functions for axios calls.

Here's my code:

```
function get_portfolio_status(agent) {

    agent.add("Here are your details. "); // the agent speaks only this

    var username = "uname";
    var password = "pwd";
    var product = "product";
    var to_speak = "";

// First call
    return login(username, password, product)
      .then((result) => {
        let SID = result.data.sid;

// Second nested function call using result of first one

        get_token(SID)
        .then((result) => {
            let JWT = result.data;
            console.log('Request token received:');

//Third call again using result of previous one

            get_portfolios(JWT)
            .then((result) => {
                let portfolios = result.data.data;
          
// Fourth call

                get_change([], JWT).then((result) => {
                  let changed_portfolio = result.data.data;
                  let to_speak = "Your portfolios are: " + changed_portfolio + portfolios;

                 console.log(to_speak); // I can see this in the Logs.

 // I cant seem to make this below work. Its just skipped due to js behavior I think

                 agent.add(to_speak + '\nWould you like to get your today\'s winners? '); 

                }).catch((err) => {console.error(err);}); 
            }).catch((err) => {console.error(err);}); 
          }).catch((err) => {console.error(err);});     
    }).catch((err) => {console.error(err);});
  }
```

The line which should work is
`agent.add(to_speak + '\nWould you like to get your today\'s winners? ');`

The agent does not speak out that line. I am quite sure this is the asynchronous behavior of JS but I am handling the promises and returning that.

The `login function` and others are simply returning axios. Some of them are POST and some are GET

For example:

```
function login(username, password, product){

  var data = {...};

  config = {
   method: 'post',
   url:'my_url',
   headers:{...}
  }

  return axios(config);
}
```

Comment: It returning the First call promise resolved, the code you added it work only for 1st promise.

Comment: On the console I can see results of all the function calls(promises)

Comment: Hello, have you enabled the [automatic text to speech](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/agents-settings#speech) in the agent? Did it work in the past or this is the first time you are trying to get output audio?

Comment: It is enabled and the payment is also integrated. I just solved the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the problem. There are two things which need to be accounted for.

1- According to Dialogflow: **The response must occur within 10 seconds for Google Assistant applications or 5 seconds for all other applications, otherwise the request will time out.** This includes the logic before the axios calls. If you are doing it in inline editor, the function call from start, otherwise the time to respond for your own webservice.
The starting point of code to the `agent.add` part in `get_portfolio_status(agent)` in my case.

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/fulfillment-webhook#webhook_response

*Side note*: As of now, only US Server has the dialog-flow integration with google assistant(for testing). Take into account the network lag in the calculation if the external API call is to Europe/ Asia.

2- The first point is not applicable right now as the processing time of this workflow is less than 2 seconds.
There was a problem in my code that the nested calls to the other functions. I had to add returns to all the nested calls.

```
return login(username, password, product)
    .then((result) => {
        let SID = result.data.sid;

        // Second nested function call using result of first one

        return get_token(SID)
            .then((result) => {
                let JWT = result.data;
                console.log('Request token received:');

                //Third call again using result of previous one

                return get_portfolios(JWT)
                    .then((result) => {
                        let portfolios = result.data.data;

                        // Fourth call

                        return get_change([], JWT).then((result) => {
                            let changed_portfolio = result.data.data;
                            let to_speak = "Your portfolios are: " + changed_portfolio + portfolios;

                            console.log(to_speak); // I can see this in the Logs.

                            // WORKS

                            agent.add(to_speak + '\nWould you like to get your today\'s winners? ');

                        }).catch((err) => {
                            console.error(err);
                        });
                    }).catch((err) => {
                        console.error(err);
                    });
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.error(err);
            });
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
    });
```

I wish the inline editor in the fulfillment service of dialog flow supported async/await. Could have enabled me to write a cleaner code and saved me a lot of hassle.

But inline editors are meant to test small prototypes so I guess its okay. In production we will deploy a separate webservice.

Answer (score 0):

You can return promise when all the promise is resolved. And resolve at the end of the last API call, until it have all the response just don't resolve it. I have made the changes in the code for reject you can implement where you required. Just resolve at the end.

```
function get_portfolio_status(agent) {

    agent.add("Here are your details. "); // the agent speaks only this

    var username = "uname";
    var password = "pwd";
    var product = "product";
    var to_speak = "";
    
    return new Promise((resolveAll, rejectAll)=>{
   

    // First call
    login(username, password, product)
      .then((result) => {
        let SID = result.data.sid;

// Second nested function call using result of first one

        get_token(SID)
        .then((result) => {
            let JWT = result.data;
            console.log('Request token received:');

//Third call again using result of previous one

            get_portfolios(JWT)
            .then((result) => {
                let portfolios = result.data.data;

// Fourth call

                get_change([], JWT).then((result) => {

                  let changed_portfolio = result.data.data;
                  let to_speak = "Your portfolios are: " + changed_portfolio + portfolios;

                 console.log(to_speak); // I can see this in the Logs.

 // I cant seem to make this below work. Its just skipped due to js behavior I think

                 agent.add(to_speak + '\nWould you like to get your today\'s winners? '); 
                resolveAll(); // Resolve when you finally have everything 
                }).catch((err) => {console.error(err);}); 
            }).catch((err) => {console.error(err);}); 
          }).catch((err) => {console.error(err);});     
    }).catch((err) => {console.error(err);});
  }

    })
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. The agent still doesnt say what I want it to.
Only shows the first agent.add(). On console, it shows the output of `console.log(to_speak);`

Comment: Can you try removing 1st agent.add("Here are your details. ") ?

Comment: Then the webhook fails as agent is empty. Either the last agent has to work or I need to explicitly add something to agent.